# Is it possible to call/execute Azure data brick script from external java api?

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, azure-databricks

Is it possible to call Azure data brick script from external java api? I want to execute this script on demand , or please suggest how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Databricks CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/), which provides an easy-to-use interface to the Azure Databricks platform.

At the same time, you can also use Databricks CLI in the Azure DevOps to integrate with Azure Databricks, for detailed info, please refer to [Continuous integration and delivery on Azure Databricks using Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-azure-devops)